# Multiply values of column with itself in R

Tags: r

I am trying to multiply elements of column with itself but am unable to do it.
I have column A with values `a, b, c`, I want answer as `(a*b + a*c + b*c)`.

For example, with
`A <- c(2, 3, 5)` the expected output is `sum(6 + 10 + 15) = 31`.

I am trying to run for loop to execute but was failing. Can anyone please provide R code to do this.

Comment: `trying to run for loop` ... you lost me right there.  Most operations in R can, and should, be vectorized.  Already I see a likely problem with your code (even though I actually see no code).

Comment: Some say [this might be a good read](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf)...

Comment: It's not such an easy question and she's a beginner, I used R for longer than I care to admit before dropping most loops.

Answer (score 4):

example data :

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(2,3,5))
```

combn will give you the combinations

```
combinations <- combn(df1$A,2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    3
# [2,]    3    5    5
```

apply with margin 2 (by columns), will do the multiplication

```
multiplied_terms <- apply(combinations,2,function(x) x[1]*x[2])
# [1]  6 10 15
```

Or shorter and more general, thanks to @zacdav :

```
multiplied_terms <- apply(combinations,2,prod)
```

then we can sum them

```
output <- sum(multiplied_terms)
# [1] 31
```

Piped for a compact solution:

```
library(magrittr)
df1$A %>% combn(2) %>% apply(2,prod) %>% sum
```

Comment: Nice.  My initial thought as well. But I think this particular problem can be done a bit easier.

Comment: `sum(apply(combinations, 2, prod))` would be a much more flexible approach if its ever needed to be a larger number set.

Comment: cool, I didn't know `prod` and didn't want to confuse OP with `Reduce`

Comment: @headpoint I summarized it into a piped solution in the end, I think it's quite 'easy', but I'll be happy to see better.

Comment: Here's a `tidyverse` variant that could probably be reworked with `data.table` into a more compact solution: `df1 %>% rownames_to_column %>% merge(.,.,by=NULL) %>% subset(rowname.x < rowname.y) %$% '*'(A.x,A.y) %>% sum`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper 'easy` is bit vague. My bad. I mainly said that since you said OP is a beginner. However,  I have benchmarked your pipped version and my `lapply` version, mine is more than four times faster than yours (based the mean 29ms to 141 ms). (I also replaced `len` by `length(A)` when I did the lapply.

Comment: cool! I think it makes sense, you loop is `n-1` long , mine `2*n`, and I `combn` is probably expensive

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, Yeah, it seem to require less computation. My initial comment is a friendly one. I was going to write an answer similar to yours then your solution appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. Approach by @Moody_Mudskipper maybe easier to extend to groups of 3 etc. But, I think this should be **much faster** since there isn't the need to actually find the combinations.

### Using *for* loop

It just goes through the vector `A` multiplying the rest of the elements until the last one.

```
len <- length(A)
res <- numeric(0)
for (j in  seq_len(len - 1))
  res <- res + sum(A[j] * A[(j+1) : len]))
res
#[1] 31
```

### Using *lapply* or *sapply*

The for loop can be replaced by using `lapply`

```
res <-  sum(unlist(lapply(1 : (len - 1), function(j) sum(A[j] * A[(j+1) : len]))))
```

or `sapply`,

```
res <- sum(sapply(1 : (len - 1), function(j) sum(A[j] * A[(j+1) : len])))
```

I didn't check which of these is the fastest.

```
# If you need to store the pairwise multiplications, then use the following;
#    res <- NULL
#    for (j in 1 : (len-1))
#       res <- c(res,  A[j] * A[(j+1) : len])
#    res
#    [1] 6 10 15
#    sum(res)
#    [1] 31
```

Comment: use `sapply` and you can skip the `unlist`

Comment: using `purr::imap_dbl` I was able to shorten it to this : `sum(imap_dbl(A,~sum(.x*A[-seq(.y)])))`

Comment: My `purr` is not good. I should have thought about the `sapply`. Fixed it.

Comment: @zacdav  I didn't say `purr` is not good (or otherwise).There isn't a single `any` in what I said...